# What build hints is needed to use Sensor in Codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to test out the Sensor CN1 package. Tests on my Android Device does not ask for any permission but then it does nothing either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will change anything but try using the location manager in your code. It will trigger the permissions and that might fix it. If it does it then this is the fix that needs to go into the cn1lib.

Comment: I've done that but no luck. Still no data from the sensor.

Comment: I suggest connecting a cable to the device and looking thru the logcat messages to try and find applicable messages. They can point us to the right issue